# Como resolver problema com Add-Migration no VSCode?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-code

Bom dia!

Olá, Bom dia!

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o Vs Code. Para isso comecei por um exercício do curso sobre Entity Framework utilizando o método Code first. Estruturei todo o código seguindo os passos do curso e instalei as packages Microsoft. O problema surge quando tento utilizar o comando para adicionar migração. Abaixo segue o código:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello gamers!");

        GamesDB games = new GamesDB();

        videogame novo = new videogame();


        novo.Title = "COF 2";
        novo.Plataform = "PS4";

        games.VideoGames.Add(novo);
        games.SaveChanges();




    }
}

 public class videogame
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Plataform { get; set; }
    
}

public class GamesDB : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<videogame> VideoGames { get; set;}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("SERVER=(localdb)\\MSSQLLOCALDB; DATABASE=videogames; TRUSTED_CONNECTION=TRUE;"); //Atenção à dupla \ pois esse caracter é especial em C#!

    }
}
```

Aqui é a mensagem que o Vs code retorna quando tento adicionar a migração:

```
Comando: dotnet ef migrations add videogames  


Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
 Testando %
```

Gostaria de saber se o erro está no comando que eu escrevi, ou se há uma package específica do Add-Migration...

Me ajudem, por favor. Tenho um projeto para desenvolver e não consigo avançar sem entender esta parte.

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Tentar conferir string de conexão do "GamesDB" e remover o pacote tool e reinstalar e limpar a solução.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como vai, Josias?! Obrigado à resposta! Tentei sua solução, entretanto sem sucesso.

Comment: Blz, e boa sorte na sua resolução do problema.